# The pattern of "X is derived N"

Tags: phrase-request, sentence-structure

Consider:

> By integrating R(r) out to the location of the first minimum, the coordination number for the first solvation shell **is derived 5.4**.

I am not sure about the bold part because no preposition I see between the derived and 5.4, maybe it is *is derived **as** 5.4*, right? Generally I can't get the pattern or structure for using a number like that.

Is it correct? what is the structure or pattern? What are other alternatives?

Comment: You'd be better off asking this on Math.SE. They would know if the jargon used is correct. But what you have there seems possible to me. I don't know why something can't be *derived 5.4*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's proofreading or domain-specific jargon - or both.

Comment: @fum you can ignore any jargon, my main question is about the usage of "derive" in "X is derived N" where N is a number.

Comment: The "as" seems pretty necessary to me, no matter what the subject.  Otherwise it's not clear what "5.4" relates to.  It could easily be derived *via* "proof pattern 5.4" or some such.

Comment: @Andrew I also think about *is derived to be 5.4* or *is derived equal to 5.4*.

Comment: @Ahmad: Note the question [Derive or differentiate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863148/derive-or-differentiate) on Math.SE. You can't really avoid the fact that ***derivative*** (and by implication, ***derive***) has domain-specific senses. If you *do* want something in that area, ask on the math site. If you *don't*, use a different verb *(established as, calculated to be,...).*

Comment: Are you sure that 5.4 isn't a reference to an equation or figure that gives the derivation? In which case, it's not supposed to be part of the text, but should be a superscript or something.

Comment: @Colin Fine: Good thinking Batman!

Answer (score 1):

> By integrating R(r) out to the location of the first minimum, the coordination number for the first solvation shell is derived 5.4.

The sentence is awkward. The idea is reasonable clear, but the positioning of "derived 5.4" is the problem. I'd suggest:

> By integrating R(r) out to the location of the first minimum, the coordination number for the first solvation shell is derived to be 5.4.
>
> By integrating R(r) out to the location of the first minimum, the derived coordination number for the first solvation shell is 5.4.